# .net framework target version vb.net

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

I made my application in visual basic 2010 .net

I just wonder which version of net framework i should set as targeted one.

which do you guys prefer so the program can run either on `xp, win7` ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8z6watww(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Plutonix according to this the best version is 2.0 ? 

Will it work if user has installed newer version ?

Answer (score 0):

.Net 4, which is the default in Visual Studio 2010, runs on XP just fine.

It's worth noting, though, that Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft, in the sense that no new security patches are released — even for critical vulnerabilities. That makes it unsafe and irresponsible to continue using XP, and most developers should now be able to assume at least Vista until someone tells them otherwise.

If you want to know what's included with the operating system, it's tricky. Under Windows XP, there is no guarantee at all that the framework will be installed, and no version of .Net is included out of the box. Windows Vista at least ships with .Net 2.0 and .Net 3.0, but there's nothing to guarantee that those features are still turned on. Same with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Framework 4 works just top notch on Windows XP (SP3)

Side note : I know it's off topic, but..

"*irresponsible to continue using XP*".. probably. I could also say shame on Microsoft, I've just to dump one very good scanner, two ink-rechargeable printers and an expensive (but nicely working) Midi USB In/Out device because the manufacturers also agree that everyone should go on and drop WinXP.. :/

By the way, it seems nowadays programmers can't produce nice cheap or freeware GREAT applications like those available in the Win98 to XP era.

- I had a Midi application that could load/create, edit, save almost any type of MIDI File with all the feature you like (show/scroll notes on a piano board, sheets, virtual guitar, beats, etc., print, ressample as WAV, WAV to MID...)
- another application almost as powerfull as Photoshop while alot more user friendly than Gimp.
- and games that were real fun you don't have to read a book before enjoying it, or that allow you to continue for hours without beeing killed in a few seconds...
- etc.

XP were really enjoyable when you had a lot more control on your files than with Vista, 7 or the worse 8. You were THE administrator, now it's Microsoft who decide who's the administrator.

---

Actually, I have a bunch of applications from other developpers that only works on XP, even by using some installer bypass trick, changing the administrator rights, etc. they won't install on Vista, 7 or 8. Some of the developpers are already dead, others impossible to get in touch with, and many has moved on and don't update their applications anymore. So I don't have their source code, and I really hope I'll find out by myself one day, so I could replace those with Win7-8-9-2025 compatible applications.

Right now, I have a desktop Win7-64 and an desktop WinXP-32, a laptop Win7-64 and a laptop WinXP-64. And that's why I don't WPF yet.

So, if someone like XP - or has *reasons* to use XP - I wouldn't recommend him to let go.